# Firebase swift ios login system error Assertion failed/Exec_BAD_INSTRUNCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, authentication, frameworks, firebase, assertion

Im trying to use the built in authentication system in firebase and followed this TuT to do so

[Firebase Login Tutorial](https://www.veasoftware.com/posts/firebase-login-tutorial-in-swift-xcode-72-ios-92)

I am able to run my app but when i go to login and type in a valid (or invalid) login email and password it crashes with this error in the console:

```
   Assertion failed: (request.URL), function -[FSRWebSocket initWithURLRequest:protocols:queue:andUserAgent:], file /Users/vikrum/dev/git/firebase-client-objc/Firebase/Firebase/Libraries/SocketRocket/FSRWebSocket.m, line 302.
(lldb)
```

When I don't type anything and hit login it crashes with this error (i have measures to prevent the app from crashing because of this, possiably side affect of the bigger issue):

```
<pre>fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value</pre>
```

The inline errors below are the same w/ both above console errors

Edit: I have noticed that in the pod directory in my app in the framework and then ios folders the contents are (My hierarchy with red error **LINKhttps://i.stack.imgur.com/IHCQw.png) highlighted in red. The directory for the 4 frameworks was iPhoneOS9.0.sdk for some reason i only have a iPhoneOS.sdk and iPhoneOS9.2.sdk also the firebase and the other framework below it have strange directory locations [(They all go to this location **LINKhttps://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6dX5.png) and i cant for the life of me figure out how to fix it (i'm not totally sure this is the error causing my app to crash after I try to log in but its the only error I have seen so it must be)

Edit 2: i've been looking around and every recent tut to make an app as of at least ios 9 has been confusing me because of this, i have seen 2 separate apps tuts where i downloaded the finale project and i wasn't able to run it because in the pod dir(all where for firebase and ios 9.2 when made and had all the frameworks for firebase) it said "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework" and i cant change it because when i go to the little dir change button i have to get into the package contents of xcode and it wont let me do that

[The inline error when I am redirected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRLDT.png)

[Second files inline error (same)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzMex.png)

Here is where i get directed when the app crashes and i get the error(2 places)

```
import Foundation     
import Firebase

let BASE_URL = "https://baseball-pitcher-app.firebaseIO.comΩΩ"

let FIREBASE_REF = Firebase(url: BASE_URL)


var CURRENT_USER: Firebase
{
    ***let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String*** ERROR IN THIS LINE

    let currentUser = Firebase(url: "\(FIREBASE_REF)").childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(userID)

    return currentUser!
}
```

One thing I did find odd was that the error was in the logout button which is weird because i've never pressed it since the error occurred.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var userUsernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var logoutButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.userUsernameTextField.delegate = self;
        self.userPasswordTextField.delegate = self;
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") != nil && CURRENT_USER.authData != nil
        {
            self.logoutButton.hidden = false
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }

    @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let email = self.userUsernameTextField.text
        let password = self.userPasswordTextField.text

        if email != "" && password != ""
        {
            FIREBASE_REF.authUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in

                if error == nil
                {
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData.uid, forKey: "uid")
                    print("Logged In :)")
                    self.logoutButton.hidden = false
                }
                else
                {
                    print(error)
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter Email and Password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func logoutButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        CURRENT_USER.unauth()**** ERROR IN THIS LINE

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(nil, forKey: "uid")
        self.logoutButton.hidden = true
    }
```

Comment: I've made more progress i believe but somehow when i updated my pods my Pods_UserLoginAndRegistration.framework disapeared anyone know how i could get it back i reinstalled and updated the pods and no dice

Comment: I was on the app store a moment ago and read that people are having problems with xcode 7.3 left and right with updating and running and building apps which could explain the reason but it still might not

Answer (score 0):

The userId id is most likely nil, and in general it's better to catch the cases in which is it nil, like this

```
if let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as? String {
    print(userID) //do something with the user id here
} else {
    print("The userID was nil.") //avoid the user id.
}
```

And the reason for the second error is that CURRENT_USER, since it never Auth'd to start with is now nil. Not sure why the button's IBAction is being called but check the actions and outlets in IB.

Also, the

> var CURRENT_USER

is a little suspect.

Based on the name of the var, I would expect it to contain the Current User (as maybe a User Class?).

However when called, it returns a Firebase object which contains a path to the current users node (/appPath/users/users node) and no other user data. It doesn't appear to be populated when a user authenticates either.

Not sure if that was the intention or if it's used somewhere else, but doing this

```
CURRENT_USER.unauth()
```

may be an issue since it doesn't contain any auth data.